# Объединить 157 файлов xlsx в один фрейм с помощью Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

Коллеги, добрый день!
Имеется 157 файлов xlsx с одинаковой структурой, без заголовоков. Составляю список файлов с помощью glob.glob. Далее, пишу цикл, который должен добавлять файлы в один фрейм, но что-то упускаю видимо. Код, который имею на данный момент:

```
in_3 = '/Оборудование/*.xlsx'  
files = glob.glob(in_3)  
for f in files:  
    a = pd.read_excel(f)  
    df = pd.DataFrame.append(a)
```

В результате получаю ошибку:

> TypeError: append() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'

Что делаю не так, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
in_3 = '/Оборудование/*.xlsx'  
files = glob.glob(in_3)

df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f, header=None) for f in files], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: MaxU, очень изящное решение! Спасибо, что всегда помогаете!

Comment: @DenisNovik, всегда пожалуйста